# Updating with jsonb_set

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have two tables:

`_building`:

| id | cityId | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34891 | 111 | {"regionId": "55", "regionName": null, "full address": "..."} |
| 09372 | 222 | {"regionId": null, "regionName": null, "full address": "..."} |

`_city`:

| id | name | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | {"regionId": "55", "regionName": "Magic region 11"} |
| 222 | B | {"regionId": "238", "regionName": "Magic region 23"} |

I need to enrich the `location` column of `_building` table with data of the `location`  column of table `_city`.

That is, after completing my task, the data of table `_building` should become like this:

| id | cityId | location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 34891 | 111 | {"regionId": "55", "regionName": "Magic region 11", "full address": "..."} |
| 09372 | 222 | {"regionId": "238", "regionName": "Magic region 23", "full address": "..."} |

I tried to use such a query, but for some reason it did not help and did not even put down the value for the `regionName` column

```
update _building b
set location = jsonb_set(
        b.location,
        '{location,regionName}',
        c.location -> 'regionName',
        false
    )
from _city c
where c.id = cityId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` on the [`jsonb_set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) is wrong, it should be `'{regionName}'` :

```
update _building b
set location = jsonb_set(
        b.location,
        '{regionName}',
        c.location -> 'regionName',
        false
    )
from _city c
where c.id = cityId
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OTYhy4YQ)